# AWS rds Layer version does not exist" when trying to deploy from serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, serverless, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to deploy a stack using serverless but I am getting this error that the layer version 31  doesn't exist while the latest version I am having is 33 which I have updated in the config file as well.
Here is the Config File:

```
    module.exports.layerArn = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-hhjhj-:13245460551:layer:rds:33"
    module.exports.securityGroupIds = "sg-0bb9bb454646451da"
    module.exports.subnetIds = "subnet-07d5454664669frdtc"
    module.exports.lambdaApiDatabaseAccessRole = "arn:aws:iam::13345353531:role/lambda-api- 
    database-access-Role-OM-AWS-SAAS-DEV-EU1"
    module.exports.ctrStream = "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-central-1:1335353666551:stream/stream-ctr- 
     bucket"
    module.exports.agentEventStream = "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-central- 
    1:13251:stream/KinesisStreamEvents"
    module.exports.domainName =  "91h7syppl4eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
    module.exports.stage = "dev"
```

Here is the full error message:

```
An error occurred: GetCallTranscriptAndRecordingLambdaFunction - Resource handler returned message:
 "Layer version arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:132334r43r341:layer:rds:31 does not exist. 
(Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 681468f7-62dd-485a-bc34-180745456f9a)" 
(RequestToken: 32eb7c85-1b21-2217-0e87-0a0229c454d2, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest).
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This question is resolved. the problem was with layer arn. after updating the layer arn, the stack deployed successfully.

Comment: giving more detail here on what you updated would be helpful